# Print matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want the output to look like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 1]     
[1, 1, 1, 1]    
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

My code right now outputs:

```
1 1 1 1    
1 1 1 1    
1 1 1 1    
1 1 1 1    

for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {  
  for (int k = 0; k < Matrix[0].length; k++) {  
    System.out.print(Matrix[j][k] + " ");  
  }  
  System.out.print("\n");  
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: How did you print spaces between the numbers? Maybe you can take a similar approach to print other characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    for (int[] row : Matrix)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print commas and brackets around your loop and after the number:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {  
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int k = 0; k < Matrix[0].length; k++) {  
        System.out.print(Matrix[j][k] + " ");  
        if (k + 1 < Matrix[0].length) System.out.print(", ")
    }  
    System.out.print("]\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print a `[` before your first line and a `]` after your last. Then add a comma before the space. Also, Java variable names start with a lower case letter (by convention). You could also use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and something like,

```
int[][] matrix = { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };
for (int[] array : matrix) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

which will produce your requested output (but will also handle jagged arrays).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<row_count;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<column_count;j++) {
            System.out.print(Matrix[i][j]+"  ");
        }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```